# R create tibble row with NA with data type dbl

Tags: r, na, tibble

How can I create one row in tibble format with data type as `<dbl>`?

(not `<lgl>` as in the example below)

```
NAs <- rep(NA, 10)
NAs1 <- t(tibble(NAs))
NAs2 <- as_tibble(NAs1)
NAs2

# # A tibble: 1 x 10
#   V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9    V10  
#   <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl> <lgl>
# 1 NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean something like `as.data.frame(matrix(NAs, nrow = 1))`?

Comment: Here is one possibility:
`tibble(col = paste0("V", 1:10), row = NA) %>% tidyr::spread(col, row)`

Comment: please not that they are in the wrong data types (these specification was not visible before because they were within "<>". Please see update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `t` over `NAs` before using `as_tibble`, e.g.,

```
> tibble::as_tibble(`class<-`(t(NAs),"numeric"))
# A tibble: 1 x 10
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: please note that the data type is lgl but I need it in dbl; (that specification was not visible before; please see updated instruction) sorry

Answer (score 2):

You can use `NA_real_` to specify the type of `NA`.

```
tibble::as_tibble(t(rep(NA_real_, 10)))

# # A tibble: 1 x 10
#      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```

From `?NA`:

> `NA` is a logical constant of length 1 which contains a missing value indicator. `NA` can be coerced to any other vector type except raw. There are also constants `NA_integer_`, `NA_real_`, `NA_complex_` and `NA_character_` of the other atomic vector types which support missing values: all of these are reserved words in the R language.

Answer (score 2):

We can also use `tibble_row`

```
library(tibble)
as_tibble_row(setNames(rep(NA_real_, 10), paste0("V", 1:10)))
# A tibble: 1 x 10
#     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
```